# Subject in PHPmail $head gets doubled and in wrong encoding

Tags: utf-8, php, subject

Im using IPN to send mail to customers after a purchase. Everythings going well except one small annoying thing. When I test to buy a product with my mail as buyer the mail in my mail inbox looks like this: http://snag.gy/grrMy.jpg <- it has double subject after itself and the first one not changed into UTF-8 - why is this? And if I click on that mail suddenly only the UTF-8 coded subject will show (as intended) like this: http://snag.gy/k5VyF.jpg

Here is the PHP code that I use:

```
$to = filter_var($ipn_post_data[payer_email], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $date = date('Y-m-d');
        $subject = "Tack för Ert köp! / Thank you for your order!";
        $headerFields = array(
    'Date: ' . date('r', $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']),
        "Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?".imap_8bit($subject)."?=",
        "From: {$to}",
    "MIME-Version: 1.0",
    "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8"
        );
 mail($to, $subject, $message,  implode("\r\n", $headerFields));
```

So the only "problem" really is that whn inbox the mails subject gets doubled with the first one with wrong encoding and it looks bad. Anyone that has input on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass `$subject` to `mail()` twice -- once in the second argument, and once in the fourth as part of `$headerFields`.

Try passing `null` as the second argument instead.

Comment: Omg you are right, I be back soon with the solution when I tested some, thanks bro!

Comment: Exactly as Blazemonger pointed out I actually pass $subject two times without realizing it. This code is just sending the UTF-8 encoded $subject: mail($to, NULL, $message,  implode("\r\n", $headerFields));

Comment: One other thing - the word "whenever" in the sentence "Welcome back to energyshop.se whenever you like!" is different in my mail inbox outside the webhost one.com which I use and in the webhost mail which I also send the same mail to, but as a copy. It has the exact same code, but in the mail outside webhost its interpreted as "whenever" as it should but in the copy, in the mail of the webhost its interpreted as "whene ver" with a white space in the middle of the word. I have copied it into a notepad and indeed there is a white space. Also not VERY important, but interesting. Do you know why?

Comment: Found solution: fixed by breaking down your $message to base64 code lik this: $message = chunk_split(base64_encode($message)); and then add this to mail header: "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"